# How do you do case-insensitive string replacement using regular expressions?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I know precisely zilch about regular expressions and figured this was as good an opportunity as any to learn at least the most basic of basics.

How do I do this case-insensitive string replacement in C# using a regular expression?

```
myString.Replace("/kg", "").Replace("/KG", "");
```

(Note that the '/' is a literal.)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "/kg", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you're going to do this a lot of times, you could do:

```
// You can reuse this object
Regex regex = new Regex("/kg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
myString = regex.Replace(myString, "");
```

Using `(?i:/kg)` would make *just that bit* of a larger regular expression case insensitive - personally I prefer to use `RegexOptions` to make an option affect the whole pattern.

MSDN has [pretty reasonable documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) of .NET regular expressions.

Comment: You left out the colon: (?i:/kg)

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "/[Kk][Gg]", String.Empty);
```

Note that it will also handle the combinations /kG and /Kg, so it does more than your string replacement example.

If you only want to handle the specific combinations /kg and /KG:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, "/(?:kg|KG)", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 2):

"/[kK][gG]" or "(?i:/kg)" will match for you.

declare a new regex object, passing in one of those as your contents. Then run regex.replace.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want to achieve. I assume you want to remove a sequence of characters after a slash?

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input,"/[a-zA-Z]+","");
```

or

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input,"/[a-z]+","",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"/kg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
    regex.Replace(input, "");
```

Comment: see Jon Skeet below, he posted first

Comment: No need for @ when there are only *forward* slashes.

Comment: yeah, I used nregex.com to create the first line of the example.  they use the @ regardless of the pattern

Comment: If you always prefix regular expressions with @, you never have to think about whether or not a given one requires it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/02/11/71188.aspx) is an example using the Regex.replace function.